# NHibernate 3.2 - MsSqlCeDialect: Dialect does not support variable limits

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have simple NHibernate Linq query (against MS SQL CE 4):

```
var productionStarts = (from p in session.Query<Production>()
                                                orderby p.Start descending
                                                select p.Start)
                                                .Distinct()
                                                .Take(maxProductionPlansPerOperation)
                                                .ToArray();
```

which in NH 3.2.0.4000 throws exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException occurred
  Message=Dialect does not support variable limits.
  Source=NHibernate
  StackTrace:
       at NHibernate.Dialect.Dialect.GetLimitString(SqlString queryString, Nullable`1 offset, Nullable`1 limit, Parameter offsetParameter, Parameter limitParameter) in d:\CSharp\NH\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Dialect\Dialect.cs:line 1707
  InnerException:
```

Problem is causing ".Take(...)". If commented out the query works.

It works fine with NH 3.1, but it no longer works NH 3.2.

In some older posts I found recommendation to use "MsSqlCe40Dialect", so I changed the dialect but no effect. I verified that NH is using correct dialect by examining properties of ISessionFactory instance.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

It is an error in the dialect, use this custom dialect to make it work:

```
public class FixedMsSqlCe40Dialect : MsSqlCe40Dialect
{
  public override bool SupportsVariableLimit
  {
    get
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```